# Set Cookie fails in ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I have a problem in Express 4.x.I can't set any cookies. I want to set a cookie via Ajax request, i do the request, my server-side res.cookie() is executed, in my response headers i can find my 'set-cookie' header with the specific name and value, but nothing happens, the cookie is not registered. I have no HttpOnly or secure flag.

Cookie set example :

```
res.cookie('my_cookie','value',{maxAge:500,secure:false,httpOnly:false});
```

What i've noticed is that if i set maxAge 500 for example, my cookie expiration date from response headers is about 5 hours ago, so i tried to add a bigger value, but nothing happened.

It is like my `set-cookie` header is ignored. I don't use AngularJS, just jQuery.

If i put the set-cookie content in document.cookie from js console, the cookie is registered..

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english .

Comment: maxAge: `Convenient option for setting the expiry time relative to the current time in milliseconds.`. If you set 1000, it will expire after 1 second. Using a higher value to `maxAge`, like 200000, or not using `maxAge` at all, still not set the cookie? How are you checking the cookie?

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I tried not to use maxAge at all and even with a higher value, same results. I'm checking the cookie in my javascript console ( when httpOnly and secure is false) and on the server side everytime i reload the page, and is nothing there. I tried using sessions, but same results, session value is not saved ..

Comment: Ok. Tested right now your code at my server, without using `cookie-parser` and just changed the `maxAge` attribute to 200000, it worked. So, `cookie-parser` is not required for it to work. I checked with `document.cookie`. Where are you setting that cookie? Can you give us more code to help you?

Comment: Actually everything i did was to create a GET requests handler, and i have the following code in it :

res.cookie('my_cookie','value',{maxAge:20000000,secure:false,httpOnly:false});
res.end();

That's all, and it's not working.. It may be smething wrong with the browser? I tried with Mozilla, but its the same ..

Comment: @CozyRin Were you able to solve this issue? I'm having the same problem. Same code in Express, can see the Set-Cookie HTTP headers in the response in Chrome dev tools. But the cookie is not getting set.

Comment: It's bananas that the maxAge option doesn't accept values in the same format as the actual max-age parameter of the set-cookie header. I was trying to set a 10 minute expiry so used a value of 600 and couldn't understand why my cookie always had a max-age of 0. Using `10 * 6e4` to convert minutes to milliseconds did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Version 4.0 removed a lot of the convenience middleware from the library for a more modular architecture; in this case you need to reference the [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser?_ga=1.51851689.1672103250.1458719730) middleware. Without it req.cookies is just an empty `{}.`

`$npm install cookie-parser`

```
var express      = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())
```

You also need it to sign cookies:

[image]

Comment: Hello and thank you! Well, i'm using cookie-parser middleware, and even so is not working..

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having this issue too. But even weirder is it works sometimes, and other times not.

Comment: Need more details. Server setup, libs, versions. What are you actually trying to do? And have you tried signing? Security settings could be forcing you to need to sign.